# How update row background colour when row updated in ng-prime datatable for dynamic columns?

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng-datatable

I want to change row colour when row updated.how set row background colour when record is updated successfully .
.html

```
<p-dataTable emptyMessage="{{tbldatamsg}}" 
      [value]="dataset" scrollable="true" 
      [style]="{'overflow':'hidden!important'}"  
      [responsive]="true" [stacked]="stacked" [filters]="GlobalFilterValue" [rows]="20" sortMode="multiple" [(selection)]="selectedRow"
       selectionMode="multiple"
      [resizableColumns]="true" columnResizeMode="expand" 
      [paginator]="true" 
      [globalFilter]="gb" 
      [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,15,20,25]"
        appendTo="body" #dt>
        <p-column styleClass="checkbox ui-resizable-column" [style]="{'width': 'auto'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
        <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols;let j=index;"
         [style]="{'width':'130px','display':col.display} " 
          [field]="col.field" 
         [header]="col.header"
         [sortable]="true" 
         [filter]="true" filterPlaceholder="Search" (mouseleave)="hoveredIndex=null" filterPlaceholder="Search"
          appendTo="body">
        </p-column>
   </p-dataTable>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved** I have used data table attribute and pass function name.

> [rowStyleClass]="lookupRowStyleClass"

.HTML

```
<p-dataTable emptyMessage="{{tbldatamsg}}" 
      [value]="dataset" scrollable="true" 
      [style]="{'overflow':'hidden!important'}" 
      [rowStyleClass]="lookupRowStyleClass"     
      [responsive]="true" [stacked]="stacked" [filters]="GlobalFilterValue" [rows]="20" sortMode="multiple" [(selection)]="selectedRow"
       selectionMode="multiple"
      [resizableColumns]="true" columnResizeMode="expand" 
      [paginator]="true" 
      [globalFilter]="gb" 
      [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,15,20,25]"
        appendTo="body" #dt>
        <p-column styleClass="checkbox ui-resizable-column" [style]="{'width': 'auto'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
        <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols;let j=index;"
         [style]="{'width':'130px','display':col.display} " 
          [field]="col.field" 
         [header]="col.header"
         [sortable]="true" 
         [filter]="true" filterPlaceholder="Search" (mouseleave)="hoveredIndex=null" filterPlaceholder="Search"
          appendTo="body">
        </p-column>
   </p-dataTable>
```

---

.ts

```
 /* Function for set css for updated rows */
  lookupRowStyleClass(rowData) {
    return rowData['modified']==='U' ?'ui-widget-updated-row':'ui-widget-NoUpdated-row';
  }
```

---

.scss

```
//Updated row
::ng-deep .ui-datatable tbody > tr.ng-star-inserted.ui-widget-updated-row{
    background-color:$updated-row-color;
}
```