# how to update row background color dynamically when record is updated?

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng-datatable

I have to change background colour of a record after updating Record in ng prime Data table.
How to do this task?

```
<p-dataTable [value]="cars" resizableColumns="true" columnResizeMode="expand">
    <p-column field="vin" header="Vin"></p-column>
    <p-column field="year" header="Year"></p-column>
    <p-column field="brand" header="Brand"></p-column>
    <p-column field="color" header="Color"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ashutosh you should try this attribute of datatable **[rowStyleClass]="lookupRowStyleClass"**

use following link to add this in your code [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51039060/how-update-row-background-colour-when-row-updated-in-ng-prime-datatable-for-dyna)

Comment: Thanks Nitin For your Help.